# Determine the Highlight color of the first character in a hyperlink

Tags: vba, ms-word, highlight

I have a hyperlink (for example [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)) that is highlighted, possibly with different colors.
I would like to determine the highlight color of each character in the hyperlink.

I used:
`r.Hyperlinks(i).Range.Characters(j).HighlightColorIndex`
For the very first (j=1) character of the hyperlink (which is w in this case) I get HighlightColorIndex=9999999, regardless of the highlight color. For all the remaining characters (ww.google.com) the code works.

I also tried `r.Hyperlinks(i).Range.Characters.First.HighlightColorIndex`, but for j=1 it returns 9999999  as well.

How could I get the value of the highlight color of the first character in the hyperlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the first character of the Range sits "between" when you query it in this manner. One way to see that is

- Display the Styles pane (in the Home tab, click on the dialog launcher of the "Styles" group)
- Click in the hyperlink around the third character and look at the style name
- Use Left Arrow until the insertion point (cursor) is just to the left of the first character in the hyperlink

When I do that I see the style name switch from "Hyperlink" to "Normal" - IOW Word is looking at what is in effect up to that point, and not at what follows. (I was surprised!). If I then hold Shift and press Right Arrow, I see the Hyperlink style selected, as I'd expect.

With Hyperlinks, the fact that these are field codes makes working with the first and last characters tricky, because "selecting" them *in code* picks up the *entire* field - that's why you're getting 999999 (= undefined - more than one color).

I could find only one way to work around this: using `SendKeys` to select the first and last characters as a user does (Shift+Right arrow). I don't like it; it's not going to be very reliable, I fear. The code will *not* work correctly if you run it from the VBA Editor - it *must* be run from the document interface where SendKeys should be executed (button in the QAT, for example). The following worked for me:

```
Sub HyperlinkHighlight()
    Dim R As word.Range, c As word.Range
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim f As word.Field
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set R = doc.content

    For i = 1 To R.Hyperlinks.Count
      R.Hyperlinks(i).Range.Characters(1).Select
      Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
      SendKeys "+({Right})", True
      DoEvents
      Debug.Print Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex

      For j = 2 To R.Hyperlinks(1).Range.Characters.Count - 1
        Debug.Print R.Hyperlinks(i).Range.Characters(j).HighlightColorIndex
      Next j

      R.Hyperlinks(i).Range.Characters(R.Hyperlinks(i).Range.Characters.Count - 1).Select
      Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      SendKeys "+({Right})", True
      DoEvents
      Debug.Print Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Cindy, thank you very much. Your solution was very helpful.